# Window Resize Shrinking

Tags: javascript, nwjs

I am having an issue regarding me resizing my window. I am using NWJS to create a native application whilst still using JavaScript.

The code below basically resizes the window whilst still maintaining a certain aspect ratio (16:9). I've also added a timeout to prevent the resize function to be called excessively.

```
var stage, w, h, doit;
window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(doit);
    doit = setTimeout(resizeCanvas, 100);
}
function resizeCanvas() {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = 9*window.innerWidth/16;
    window.resizeTo(w,h);

    stage.canvas.width = w;
    stage.canvas.height = h;
```

I would assume that would work, however I seem to be running into the window just collapsing back into the minimum width (1280x720). I am not sure why this is happening.

Example of the collapsing window - https://gyazo.com/6a049f3d006afecba0775fee26656cff

Thank you, it would really help if a solution could be found.

Comment: Shouldn't the height calculation be h = 9*window.innerWidth/16 ?

Comment: From what I see it seems like the resize event is triggered in chain, thus resulting in a 1280x720 window.
Also why do your need to clear the timeout ?

Comment: @Amit, ah that was a small error which I fixed but didn't update here. The same error persists, but it now also shrinks the height as well.

Comment: @Germain Someone did recommend me to do clearTimeout, but I just realised it is completely unnecessary. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug with NWJS, where window.innerWidth might not be returning the new resized value properly. Can you try getting this value using a console.log ?

Comment: @Amit Here are the logged width and height values - https://gyazo.com/054ffa1142f18d5a8ef4c9dd43ebb8e5

Comment: Ok looks like there is no issue. Instead of window.resizeTo(w, h), can you try this: gui.Window.get().resizeTo(w, h) ? You might have to require nw.gui like this: var gui = require('nw.gui')

Comment: @Amit Unfortunately the exact same issue still persists yet again. It really is perplexing.